# Express.js - Retrieve one row from MySQL database

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express

I'm trying to retrieve a single row from the mysql database and display it on the page (using handlebars).

This is my API:

```
//app.js
app.get('/human/view/:request', api.getHuman);

---------------

//api.js
var mysql = require('mysql');

var client = mysql.createConnection({
host        :   'localhost',
user        :   'vlad',
password    :   'xxx',
database    :   'resources'
});

exports.getHuman = function(req, res) {

client.query('SELECT * FROM humans WHERE request = ?', req.params.request, function(err, result) {
    if (err) {
        throw err;
    }

    res.render('viewHuman', { title: 'View Resources', result: result });
});
}

-----------------------------------------

// viewHuman View

<h2>{{ result.firstname }} + ' ' + {{ result.lastName }}</h2>
<hr>

<h4>Request ID</h4>
<p> {{ result.request }} </p>
<hr>
.......
```

Still, whenever I try to retrieve that entry, I get the view rendered, but all my fields are empty.

I am looking forward to your feedback!

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line

```
    res.render('viewHuman', { title: 'View Resources', result: result[0] });
```

The callback return rows, as an array of objects, so just pass the first one to the view.